# whether activemq will send the message again when throw RuntimeException in onmessage?

Tags: activemq-classic

```
@Override  
public void onMessage(final Message message) {  
    this.handleThreadPool.execute(new Runnable() {  
        public void run() {  
            try {       
                 MultiThreadMessageListener.this.messageHandler.handle(message);  
            } catch (Exception e) {  
                throw new RuntimeException(e);  
            }  
        }  
    });
```

I want to know whether activemq will send the message again when throw  `RuntimeException` ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are handling the Message in a Thread inside your own executor so the answer would be, Nope.  Once onMessage returns the Message would be acknowledge as consumed if you are using auto acknowledge mode for instance.